# 2008 R2 nas access issues

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-attached-storage

We have 6 windows 2008 R2 servers with IIS on it with shared configuration. And there is one nas device where all the data is stored. IIS sites access those data using username\workgroupname & password specified in IIS's "connect as" option.

We can access that same nas using \nas name.

But since last few days \nas share stops working suddenly. We came to following resolution on temporary basis but wont to know the exact root cause for such behaviour.

net use \nas /delete

net use \nas\ipc$ /user:workgroupname\username password

After hitting above commands \nas access works perfectly but would like to know the permanent solution instead of this manual turnaround.

Thanks,

Sandesh

Comment: Which NAS are you using? Synology? QNAP? Which firmware version?  Is Windows ACL permissions enabled? Need some more info on the NAS itself...

Comment: its a netapp nas.